# Android drag drop listview with sections

Tags: java, android, listview, drag-and-drop

I want to develop a drag and drop `ListView` in android which should have sections or separators in between the `ListItems`.

i found the source for drag and drop from here
http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html?showComment=1343729578427

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

but how to implement the functionality for sections or separators

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google it dude! there are various ways, check this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns&hl=en

Comment: I have googled before posting this, but only samples I get are having drag and drop functionality while adding sections or saperatos in between Items is missing, If anybody can help that would be grt. thanks.

Comment: Any help above would be appreciated? I have still not got the solution